# Sed search and append starting from the bottom of a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal

How can I get sed to search a file from the bottom and find the first string it hits, then append after that?  ie:

```
#file.test

Include sumeStuff1
Include sumeStuff2
Include sumeStuff3
Include sumeStuff4
Include sumeStuff5
Include sumeStuff6
Include sumeStuff7
Include sumeStuff8
Include SED_ENTRY
```

I know that I can do:

```
find -type f -name "file.test" | xargs sed -i "s/Include somestuff8/Include somestuff8\nInclude SED_ENTRY/g"
```

but, the problem is, I am building a script where I don't know what is the EXACT line is that is the last Include line, so I need to search from the bottom and then add a line after the last Include line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ tac a | awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /^Include/ && p==1 {print "Include SED_ENTRY"; print; p=0}1' | tac
Include sumeStuff1
Include sumeStuff2
Include sumeStuff3
Include sumeStuff4
Include sumeStuff5
Include sumeStuff6
Include sumeStuff7
Include sumeStuff8
Include sumeStuff8
Include SED_ENTRY
```

#### Explanation

- `tac` prints a file the other way round.
- `awk 'BEGIN{p=1} /^Include/ && p==1 {print "Include SED_ENTRY"; print; p=0}1'` adds the `"Include SED_ENTRY"` before the first line starting with `"Include"` and flags it so that the line is not printed again.
- `tac` finally reverses the output.

Comment: Unfortunately tac doesn't exist on OSX :(

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^YOUR_PAT$/)n=NR;next}FNR==n{$0="SED_ENTRY"}7' file file
```

for your example, it would be:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{if(/^Include sumeStuff8$/)n=NR;next}FNR==n{$0="Include SED_ENTRY"}7' file file
```

Comment: I like it! Using the same file twice sounds good. However, as the `Include sumeStuff8` line has to be printed as well, I suggest to use: `7; FNR==n{print "Include SED_ENTRY"}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1 h
$ {/^Include/ s/$/\
/ }
1! H
$ {x;s/\(.*Include [^[:cntrl:]]\{1,\}\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\2Include SED_ENTRY\2\3/p;}' YourFile
```